# Compile project that references installed project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have a library module that I created through Maven, there is `pom.xml` what get dependencies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.18.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<groupId>com.example.library</groupId>
<artifactId>commons</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>commons</name>
<description>common dependencies library</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

With the above pom, I successfully installed it into the local maven repository by using `mvn install`.

In another project `my-service`, which uses this installed library, within the IntelliJ IDEA, it is fine compiling and running. There is the `pom.xml` for the `my-service`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>my-service</name>
    <description>My Services</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.18.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- other dependencies ... -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example.library</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

However, when running with `mvn compile`, I got the following errors:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project my-service: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /Users/doe/IdeaProjects/my-service/src/main/java/com/example/myservice/configs/WebSecurityConfig.java:[3,45] package com.example.library.commons.filters does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/doe/IdeaProjects/my-service/src/main/java/com/example/myservice/configs/WebSecurityConfig.java:[17,13] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class SessionFilter
[ERROR] location: class com.example.myservice.configs.WebSecurityConfig
[ERROR] /Users/doe/IdeaProjects/my-service/src/main/java/com/example/myservice/configs/WebSecurityConfig.java:[19,36] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class SessionFilter
[ERROR] location: class com.example.myservice.configs.WebSecurityConfig
```

The library project is created as part of the IntelliJ IDEA module within the same project as the `my-service` module. I guess the IntelliJ IDEA knows how to internally references module to compile the depending modules, but with Maven, it is a different story.

My goal is to compile and package the my-service module as a single jar that includes the `commons` library module. Now I can't even get it to compile with Maven, what did I do wrong?

Apache Maven version 3.3.9 . Operating system: OS X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the Spring-boot-maven plugin is not needed in the library project because a library doesn't need to produce an executable ueber jar. After removing the plugin, it compiles successfully.